# I tried to install ttn package and I can't

Tags: python

I tried to install ttn package and I can't! Exceptions are:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 433, in _download_url
    for chunk in resp_read(4096):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 421, in resp_read
    chunk_size, decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 225, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 174, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 602, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: The read operation timed out

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I followed this eg: https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/applications/python//#installation

My OS:

```
$: lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

$: uname -a
Linux ubuntu64-phytec-User 4.4.0-96-generic #119~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 08:40:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Have any suggestions? Maybe it doesn't work because it's not Win?

Comment: Is the computer where you are trying to install connected to the Internet?

Comment: Looks like a bad internet connection to me